# Search in files line by line python 2.7 in an array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file looks like this:

```
(...)
- src: git+[server]
  name: main
  version: master

- src: git+[server]
  name: sec
  version: master

- src: git+[server]
  name: compiler
  version: master

- src: git[server]
  name: libs
  version: master

- src: git[server]
  name: crosscomp
  version: master
(...)
```

and I only want to change the version after

> name: main

and

> name: sec

So my idea was to read the whole file line by line into an array and check if the line begins with the name: master or name: sec. (with `startswith()`)

But how can I access the line after the finding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process the lines in pairs and update the next line whenever the you find a matching line. You'll need to overwrite the contents of the file with new lines at the end.

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for i in range(len(lines)-1):
        if 'name: main' in lines[i] or 'name: sec' in lines[i]:
            lines[i+1] = lines[i+1].replace('master', 'newversion')

    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
maseterIndex = [i for i, x in enumerate(array) if x == "name: master"]
secIndex = [i for i, x in enumerate(array) if x == "name: sec"]
mergedlist = maseterIndex + secIndex
for index in mergedlist:
    #do something with next line
    print array[index+1]
```